# Difference between --cache-to/from and --mount type=cache in docker buildx build

Tags: docker, caching, dockerfile, containers

According to the official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/backends/#command-syntax), in order to leverage a cache backend in `docker buildx build`, you need to use the `--cache-from/to` flags.

This makes sense as intuitively it signifies the place where the build result will be cached to (`--cache-to`) and what cache it will use to speed up the build process (`--cache-from`).

However, there is another alternative (?) of using cache with the `mount` option within the `RUN` [directive](https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/), as in: (official example)

```
RUN \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
```

In the last example where these (`apt` packages in our case) will be retrieved from?

Is the cache backend (`s3`, `gha` etc) applicable in this case?

Are these two cases complementary or orthogonal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are solving two different problems.

`--cache-to/from` is used to store the result of a build step and reuse it in future builds, avoiding the need to run the command again. This is stored in a persistent location outside of the builder, like on a registry, so that other builders can skip already completed steps of a build even if the image wasn't built on the local system.

`--mount type=cache` creates a mount inside the temporary container that's executed in a RUN step. This mount is reused in later executions of the build when the step itself is not cached. This is useful when a step pulls down a lot of external dependencies that do not need to be in the image and can safely be reused between builds. The storage of the mount cache is local to the builder and is an empty directory on first use.

Comment: Thanks that explains a lot. If I am getting this, the second case (`mount`) does not make much sense in a CI system unless for example the `/var/cache/apt` is an external filestore (say NFS)? Is this correct?

Comment: The `--mount type=cache` doesn't make sense with an ephemeral builder because that cache is deleted when the builder is deleted. If the docker builder is persistent and rebuilding similar images, then it can have a dramatic speed up even when it's not possible to cache the layer itself (e.g. code changes with one new dependency, you don't need to download all the previous dependencies again).

Comment: `docker buildx build --cache-to` allows one to export the _layer_ cache, if I'm reading this correctly?  So if you rebuilt the same image somewhere else it might be able to skip an entire `RUN some-package-manager install` step;  `RUN --mount=type=cache` will persist individual downloaded packages if correctly configured, but only on a single builder?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes. Think of `--mount=type=cache` as buildx mounting a named volume for that step. The volume doesn't go into the image, but is very useful to reuse content in a directory between builds.