# Using docker RUN --mount=type=cache

Tags: docker, go, caching, build

I'm not fully understand `docker`'s `RUN --mount=type=cache` mechanism, even having read the following articles,

- https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/
- https://vsupalov.com/buildkit-cache-mount-dockerfile/
- [Difference between --cache-to/from and --mount type=cache in docker buildx build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76351391/difference-between-cache-to-from-and-mount-type-cache-in-docker-buildx-build)
- **mount=type=cache more in-depth explanation** https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1673

This is my simple dockerfile:

```
FROM debian

ENV GOPATH=/go
WORKDIR ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/my/prj

# Copy sources
COPY ./ ./
RUN ls -l
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=${GOPATH} ls -l
```

What I was trying to do is to cache the `go mod download` and all go build caches, however, this is what I'm getting:

```
#5 [internal] load build context
#5 transferring context: 2.04kB done
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [builder 2/5] WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/my/prj
#6 CACHED

#7 [builder 3/5] COPY ./ ./
#7 DONE 0.0s

#8 [builder 4/5] RUN ls -l
#8 1.555 total 312
#8 1.555 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 23796 Dec  2 21:59 History.md
#8 1.555 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1097 Dec  2 21:59 LICENSE
#8 1.555 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   600 Dec  2 21:59 Makefile
#8 1.555 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    15 Dec  2 21:59 Procfile
#8 1.555 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 57837 Dec  2 21:59 README.md
#8 1.555 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   714 Dec  2 21:59 benchmark.sh
#8 1.555 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6093 Dec  2 21:59 controllers.go
#8 1.555 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3823 Dec  2 21:59 error.go
#8 1.555 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   459 Dec  2 21:59 error_test.go
#8 1.555 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   276 Dec  2 21:59 go.mod
#8 1.555 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6439 Dec  2 21:59 go.sum
. . . 
#8 1.555 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   318 Dec  2 21:59 version.go
#8 DONE 1.6s

#9 [builder 5/5] RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/go ls -l
#9 1.881 total 4
#9 1.881 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 45 Dec  2 22:58 go.mod
#9 DONE 1.9s
```

Why all of sudden my files are gone when using `--mount=type=cache`?
How to clear such `--mount=type=cache` while retaining all other docker caches like step caches or apt caches?
Is it still possible to cache the `go mod download` and all go build caches, when using `COPY . .`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.2` is missing in the Dockerfile. Just make sure it's declared as the first line in the Dockerfile. This comment tells Docker that you're using BuildKit features.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).